# Mysql Trigger with if statment doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

The following code in my trigger doesn't work when I add a record in the table 'record' (column seen of table 'person' wasn't updated when adding a record in 'record')

```
IF ((select CAST(max(`date`) AS DATE) from `record` where x =   NEW.x and (`date` != NEW.`date`) and is_deleted = 0) != null) THEN 
    UPDATE person set seen = 1;              
END IF
```

Comment: Doesn't work means?

Comment: Do you get any errors, when it doesn't work?

Comment: 'Doesn't work' means that table person wasn't updated (column seen doesn't contain value 1) when I add a row in Assessment

Comment: and how are we supposed to help you without: sample data, error messages?

Comment: I dont' have any error, trigger creation pass without errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue was in the condition on date that's why I get null in query, so I added the conditions

```
AND day(`date`) < day(NEW.`date`) 
AND month(`date`) <= month(NEW.`date`) 
AND year(`date`) <= year(NEW.`date`)
```

then I got the right record.